# Getting offset of datetimeoffset in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server I need to find the offset of a given `datetimeoffset(7)`.

I have researched the documentation and there are all ways to change the offset but not a way to know the offset of a particular value (sorry if I missed it).

Well I came up with the following piece of code that I find too complicated although seems to work.

```
DECLARE @datetimeOffset datetimeoffset(7)

SET @datetimeOffset = CAST('2007-05-08 22:35:29.1234567-05:00' AS datetimeoffset(7))

DECLARE @result datetimeoffset(7)
DECLARE @offsetMin int

SET @offsetMin = DATEDIFF(mi, cast(SWITCHOFFSET(@datetimeOffset, '+00:00') as datetime), cast(@datetimeOffset as datetime)) 

SELECT @offsetMin
```

I still have to do the conversion to the +00:00 format but wanted to check if there is a better way of doing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

- [The `DATEPART` function has a `tz` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) which returns the value's UTC offset in `int` minutes.
- [`DATENAME` also supports the `tz` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and returns the *formatted* UTC offset in the form `[+-]HH:MM`

  - Note that a `datetimeoffset` value only contains a scalar UTC offset value, it does not contain any time-zone information at all (as multiple timezones can and do share the same offset), so it is not possible to use `DATEPART`/`DATENAME` to get the timezone name.

```sql
DECLARE @dateTimeOffsetValue_USPacific datetimeoffset(7) = '2022-07-24 12:34:56-07:00';
DECLARE @dateTimeOffsetValue_UTC       datetimeoffset(7) = '2022-07-24 19:34:56Z';
DECLARE @dateTimeOffsetValue_Bendigo   datetimeoffset(7) = '2022-07-25 05:34:56+10:00';

SELECT
    'US Pacific' AS "Zone",
    @dateTimeOffsetValue_USPacific AS "Value",
    DATEPART( tzoffset, @dateTimeOffsetValue_USPacific ) AS OffsetMinutes,
    DATENAME( tzoffset, @dateTimeOffsetValue_USPacific ) AS OffsetHHMM

UNION ALL

SELECT
    'UTC' AS "Zone",
    @dateTimeOffsetValue_UTC AS "Value",
    DATEPART( tzoffset, @dateTimeOffsetValue_UTC ) AS OffsetMinutes,
    DATENAME( tzoffset, @dateTimeOffsetValue_UTC ) AS OffsetHHMM

UNION ALL

SELECT
    'Australian Eastern Standard Time' AS "Zone",
    @dateTimeOffsetValue_Bendigo AS "Value",
    DATEPART( tzoffset, @dateTimeOffsetValue_Bendigo ) AS OffsetMinutes,
    DATENAME( tzoffset, @dateTimeOffsetValue_Bendigo ) AS OffsetHHMM;
```

Gives this result:

| Zone | Value | OffsetMinutes | OffsetHHMM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `'US Pacific'` | `2022-07-24 12:34:56.0000000 -07:00` | `-420` | `'-07:00'` |
| `'UTC'` | `2022-07-24 19:34:56.0000000 +00:00` | `0` | `'+00:00'` |
| `'Australian Eastern Standard Time'` | `2022-07-25 05:34:56.0000000 +10:00` | `600` | `'+10:00'` |

Comment: You can also get the DATENAME(tz, @datetimeoffset) to get the offset as a varchar.

Comment: `TZOFFSET` works in place of `tz` and, for what it's worth, is recognized by the SSMS syntax highlighter.