# How to get the Time Offset converted to an Int or added to the datetime column (with TSQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, timezone-offset

I have the following script giving me:

```
  Select    ENDTIME_UTC AT TIME ZONE 'E. South America Standard Time' as TransactionDate_ESAST
            ,ENDTIME_UTC as TransactionDate
    From   Table_CYC
  --Results: 2019-11-09 21:02:28.000 -03:00, 2019-11-09 21:02:28.000
```

However, I would want it either -3 (as an integer for just the offset portion) or 2019-11-09 18:02:28.000, where the hour is subtracted by three.

What would be the best way to go about this?
Thanks,
Yolanda

Answer (score 1):

As currently written you are asserting that the existing value is in Brasilia time and not performing any time zone conversion.  Instead, you need to assert that the existing value is in UTC and then convert to Brasilia time.

This is done by calling `AT TIME ZONE` *twice*.

```
SELECT ENDTIME_UTC AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'E. South America Standard Time'
```

- The first `AT TIME ZONE` creates a `datetimeoffset` from your input `datetime` asserting that it should be applied with the UTC time zone.
- The second `AT TIME ZONE` then converts from that `datetimeoffset` to another `datetimeoffset` with the given time zone.

Note that this is only necessary because your original field is of type `datetime` (or `datetime2`, etc.).  If instead your field was a `datetimeoffset`, then your original code would work fine.

Comment: As far as getting the offset by itself, after performing the above you can use the technique [described in this  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15056465/634824) to extract the offset from the result.